# Dual-monitor (TwinView) vertical, rotated display: how to make mouse span horizontally?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, mouse, rotate-monitor

In a dual-monitor configuration (I happen to employing NVIDIA, but not sure it matters), want to both:

1. display each monitor vertically, in "portrait" mode (rotated, with
   [xrandr(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xrandr.1.html)),
2. and make mouse movement/transition span horizontally between the monitors.

By "default" in vertically-rotated config, the mouse spans between monitors only from bottom of one monitor and top of the other.  Extremely annoying, almost unusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one monitor be "above" (or "below") the other in [nvidia-settings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/nvidia-settings.1.html) "X Server Display Configuration", as opposed to being "the right/left of" the other.

My head still explodes trying to figure out why, but I just think of it as a "relative" thing.  Works for me in Ubuntu 12.04.  Had to add `xrandr -o left` to [session startup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup) to get my display rotate to work across X-server restarts (reboots, re-logins, etc).